# Accessing the controller session values in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I want to perform add and remove operations based on the rules for dropdownlist in jquery. I am binding the data to dropdownlist in controller and saved those values in session variable. i want to use that session value in jquery for remove and append operation based on data value.

Kindly suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Razor view engine, just access to your session object by using the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var sessionItem = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["session-item-name"]';
    //your logic code goes here
    //

</script>
```